# Kotlin - Android Studio - Public var problem

Tags: android, kotlin, variables

[Codes image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyp0v.png)

I have a public var named dataList in my MainActivity. I showed that in top of the picture. On bottom of the picture i just add something yo dataList and started a fragment. I can access to new items (that i just added) in onCreate. But if i just try to access from my fragment i can't? I can access default variables but i can't access new added items from fragment. How can i add globally?

This is what i do in my fragment:

```
mainAdapter = todoAdapter(MainActivity().dataList[0][2])
```

Sorry for bad english

Comment: You can try it like `mainAdapter = todoAdapter((activity as MainActivity).dataList[0][2])`

Comment: Oh thank you, that worked. I didn't see this (... as ...) syntax. How can i search that?

Comment: And now I'm changing the dataList from another activities. Can't i just change globally? Or how can i solve this problem?@mehmetsalimayan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to access and/or modify your list from different parts of your application.

For that, I suggest you use a singleton object.

For example:

```
object GlobalObject{
  var dataList : MutableList<MutableList<aTodo>> = mutableListOf(
      mutableListOf(
          aTodo("hey",false,"cat1")
      ),
      mutableListOf(
          aTodo("hey2",false,"cat2")
      )
  )
}
```

Once you have that, you can use it like this anywhere from your application:

```
GlobalObject.dataList
```